# Zend Framework 2 : Why appendScript loaded at last

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework2

I want to load some inline JS script after specified file but it loads at last. How i load that append script at my required position. Here is my code snippets.

```
$this->inlineScript()
     ->offsetSetFile(57, $this->basePath('/admin_assets/plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js'))
     ->offsetSetFile(58, $this->basePath('/admin_assets/scripts/app.js'));

$this->inlineScript()->appendScript('jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    App.init();
    });
');

 $this->inlineScript()->offsetSetFile(
     59,
     $this->basePath('/admin_assets/plugins/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js')
 );      

 echo $this->inlineScript();
```

Actually i want to load inline script `App.init()` after immediate file `app.js`. How can i achieve that.

Comment: are you trying to load this at the head of the file or at the body?

Answer (score 0):

You should use method:

```
offsetSetScript($index, $script, $type = 'text/javascript', $attrs = array());
```

instead of:

```
appendScript($script, $type = 'text/javascript', $attrs = array());
```

then you can specify index of the script to modify loading order.

This is something that you need:

```
$this->inlineScript()
     ->offsetSetFile(57, $this->basePath('/admin_assets/plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js'))
     ->offsetSetFile(58, $this->basePath('/admin_assets/scripts/app.js'));

$this->inlineScript()->offsetSetScript(59, 'jQuery(document).ready(function() {  

        App.init();
});');     

$this->inlineScript()->offsetSetFile(60, $this->basePath('/admin_assets/plugins/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js'));      

echo $this->inlineScript();
```

You can find more details in documentation: [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.head-script.html)